FInding a maximum-weight matching that is substantially larger than the second-best
Given a  weighted complete bipartite graph, there are well-known polytime algorithms for finding a maximum-weight perfect matching. I am interested in comparing the weight of a perfect matching with the weights of other perfect matchings.
Given a positive number $T$, can we decide in polytime whether there exists a perfect matching $M$, such that  $weight(M) >= weight(N)+T$ for every perfect matching $N\neq M$? In other words: can we decide if the maximum weight of a perfect matching is larger than the second-highest weight by at least $T$?

Yes.  In fact, you can even explicitly find the second-largest perfect matching (or one such, if there are ties).
Iterate over all edges $(u,v)$ such that $(u,v) \notin M$.  For each such, force $(u,v)$ to be matched (i.e., to be in $N$), delete $u,v$ from the graph, then find the largest perfect matching in the remaining graph.  This gives the largest perfect matching containing $(u,v)$.  Now take the largest of all such matchings obtained in this way.  This will be the second-largest perfect matching.  Then you can check whether its weight satisfies $\text{weight}(M) \ge \text{weight}(N)+T$.
